# Pop up window getting replaced if opened from another session

Tags: javascript, jsp

In Java web application (JSF), I have a Person form which has Add details button on click of this button, i'm opening a pop up window using java script but i haven't closed this pop up window yet. Now if i open a another session of the same application and try to add details for another person, it replaces the pop up window which was opened with previous session. How to avoid such scenario ?

```
var url = contextpath+'person/AddDetails.jsp';
var modalprops = "height=310,width=400,scrollbars=on,status=no;menubar=no,resizable=no";
window.open(url, 'adddetails', modalprops, false);
```

I'm not good at UI technologies :(, hence this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each window a unique name instead of having them all be called "adddetails".